# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jweb.beans.News

Tags: java, servlets

I got this error but I don't understand where is the problem, I made the same thing for user in my project and it's working well :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - L''exécution de la servlet a lancé une exception
type Rapport d''exception
message L''exécution de la servlet a lancé une exception

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la             requête.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: L''exécution de la servlet a lancé une exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jweb/beans/News
com.jweb.servlets.newsmanagement.doPost(newsmanagement.java:44)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jweb.beans.News
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
com.jweb.servlets.newsmanagement.doPost(newsmanagement.java:44)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

News.java, the file that describe a news:

```
package com.jweb.beans;

public class News {
private int id;
private String object;
private String message;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getObject() {
    return object;
}
public void setObject(String object) {
    this.object = object;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

Then i create a new "News" in my method post :

```
News news = new News();
news.setObject(request.getParameter("object"));
news.setMessage(request.getParameter("message"));
```

Comment: You're not deploying whatever it is that has `com.jweb.beans.News`, just like the error message says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the two things could have happened. You will need to investigate the server deployment directory:

1. Your class file is missing when deployed. Make sure your class file is present in the webapp under the "classes" directory path(follow package name) OR library folder contains the JAR(holds the file) that you need.
2. This is more subtle. Perhaps you have MORE than one version of the class deployed in your web app. For example you have this class in your "classes" directory AND it is also present in the library JAR, in that case server will not know which class to load.

Comment: Thanks guy !! I renamed News by Newsletter and it's working now ;)